# Conda environments' name missing after mamba installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, conda, virtualenv, mamba

After installing mamba and creating an environment, all the names of my previous conda environments are missing. I can see their path and even activate them if I do:

`conda activate /environment/path`

this is what it looks like when I do:

`conda env list`

output:

```
 conda environments:

base                  *  /home/emalv/mambaforge3
moose                    /home/emalv/mambaforge3/envs/moose
                         /home/emalv/miniconda3
                         /home/emalv/opt/miniconda3
                         /home/emalv/opt/miniconda3/envs/ase
                         /home/emalv/opt/miniconda3/envs/deepmd
                         /home/emalv/opt/miniconda3/envs/env_soap
                         /home/emalv/opt/miniconda3/envs/moose
                         /home/emalv/opt/miniconda3/envs/pfmod
                         /home/emalv/opt/miniconda3/envs/pmg
                         /home/emalv/opt/miniconda3/envs/pycalphad-garces
```

I tried to activate my environment called "pycalphad-garces" but it didn't work using the standard:

`conda activate pycalphad-garces`

got this:
output:

```
EnvironmentNameNotFound: Could not find conda environment: pycalphad-garces
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

I would expect to get the environment activated. I could activate this environment by doing:

`conda activate /home/emalv/opt/miniconda3/envs/pycalphad-garces`

This is how my .bashrc looks like this regarding conda initialization:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>                                                      
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!                  
__conda_setup="$('/home/emalv/mambaforge3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then                                                           
    eval "$__conda_setup"                                                       
else                                                                            
    if [ -f "/home/emalv/mambaforge3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then            
        . "/home/emalv/mambaforge3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"                      
    else                                                                        
        export PATH="/home/emalv/mambaforge3/bin:$PATH"                         
    fi                                                                          
fi                                                                              
unset __conda_setup                                                             
                                                                                
if [ -f "/home/emalv/mambaforge3/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh" ]; then                
    . "/home/emalv/mambaforge3/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh"                          
fi                                                                              
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Any suggestion how to get the names back and be able to activate using them?

Thanks folks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to point the system to the existing environments, in my case "/Users/fk/miniconda3/envs/".
Try running this:

```
conda config --append envs_dirs /Users/fk/miniconda3/envs/
```

Afterwards both mamba and conda can be used to activate the envs.